# SQL Join without nulls on multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, mariadb

I'm a bit of a SQL noob so excuse me if I'm barking up the wrong tree! Here's the problem:

I have one table called 'networkdata' with some network traffic data. This table has one column called MAC_Source and one called MAC_Dest, each of which contains MAC addresses.

I have a second table called 'knownmacs' that contains two columns, one with MAC addresses, one with 'friendly' names.

Note that not all MAC addresses in the two columns of the 'networkdata' table are in the 'knownmacs' table.

What I'd like to do is create a query that will return the 'networkdata' table with the MAC addresses in the MAC_Source column and the MAC_Dest column replaced with the friendly names WHERE KNOWN - where the MAC addresses don't appear in the knownmacs table I want the original value in each column returned. I DO NOT want to replace the data in the networkdata table, just return a query with the data substituted as above.

To show you visually:

Table networkdata:

```
MAC_Source        | MAC_Dest          | Other cols
---------------------------------------------------
AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF   FF:EE:DD:CC:BB:AA   Other data
11:22:33:44:55:66   66:55:44:33:22:11   Other data
```

Table knownmacs:

```
MAC_Address       | Friendlyname
-------------------------------------------
AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF   Computer 1
66:55:44:33:22:11   Computer 2
```

Query result:

```
MAC_Source        | MAC_Dest          | Other cols
---------------------------------------------------
Computer 1          FF:EE:DD:CC:BB:AA   Other data
11:22:33:44:55:66   Computer 2          Other data
```

I've tried a LEFT JOIN for MAC_Source but I just get two extra columns and don't know how to then combine (or replace or whatever) to get just one column. I then don't know how to do the second column...

Hope that makes sense, if not then please just ask for more details! I'm using MariaDB 5 if that makes any difference.

Many thanks in advance,

Thinqer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a `left join` and `coalesce()`:

```
select coalesce(kms.name, kms.mac_source) as mac_source,
       coalesce(kms.name, kms.mac_dest) as mac_dest,
       . . .
from networkdata nd left join
     knownmacs kms
     on nd.mac_source = kms.mac left join
     knownmacs kmd
     on nd.mac_dest = kms.mac;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Gordon - just a couple of typos in your solution but otherwise it worked exactly as hoped!

Revised as follows:

```
select coalesce(kms.name, nd.mac_source) as mac_source,
       coalesce(kmd.name, nd.mac_dest) as mac_dest,
       . . .
from networkdata nd left join
     knownmacs kms
     on nd.mac_source = kms.mac left join
     knownmacs kmd
     on nd.mac_dest = kms.mac;
```